# Drag and Drop Files in CKEditor (php codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

> I am working on CKEditor. CKEditor provides basic level functionality
>   for Template editing. Now I want extra feature for drag and drop
>   external files in CKEditor. Is there any free plugin or API available
>   by which I can develope drag and drop functionality ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ok sorry for that let me elaborate more.